# java use function as parameter and only care about the return value of it

Tags: java, lambda

How to implement this function below

```
public T myFunction(Function<T> func)  //T is the return type
{
  //...some code
  return func();
}
```

And I can use the function like below, and don't need to declare parameters a, b, c in myFunction

```
myType result = myFunction(() -> doSomething(a, b , c))
```

Comment: Why would you even want to wrap the function call in another function and not assign `doSomething(a, b, c)` directly? Anyhow you might want to take a look at `java.util.function.Supplier`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right functional interface to use then is `Supplier<T>`. It doesn't have an "input" type parameter:

```
public <T> T myFunction(Supplier<T> func) {
    // myFunction logic 
    return func.get();
}
```

And the invocation will be just as you have it, assuming `doSomething()` has `myType` as return type.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Java is not a "Functional" language. So when you define a method like `myFunction(Function<T> func)` you specified, myFunction requires an Object that extends the Interface Function. Function in java declares a single method `R apply(T t)` in this case, Function takes a single argument. There are additional Interfaces that are part of the Java SDK such as `BiFunction` which has an apply method that takes two arguments. If you need a method that will take a "Function" requiring three parameters you will have to declare an Interface with those specifics. Or you could use something like. [Apache Commons TriFunction](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/function/TriFunction.html)